# Spatial data in oracle sql - distance between two points

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial

I try to calculate distance between two point stored as POINT.
This does not work.
Work in SQL developer.

```
select sdo_geom.sdo_distance(d.start_geo, d.end_geo) as distance
from   distances d
```

Gives error: ORA-06553: PLS-306

[image: Data]

[image: Description of the table]

Comment: please show the table definition of distances table.

Comment: Added to the first message

Comment: Looks like the procedure requires parameters of type SDO_GEOMETRY, no?  Not varchar2?

Comment: @OldProgrammer is right.  Also, you need to specify a 3rd parameter for the tolerance.  See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/data-model.htm#SPATL450.

Comment: So Step #1 before posting to SO - read the documentation.  :)

Comment: Try sth like this but does not help.
btw. how to change data type to sdo_geometry data stored as varchar2?

SELECT
    sdo_geom.sdo_distance(sdo_geom.sdo_geometry(2001, null, d.start_geo, NULL, NULL), sdo_geom.sdo_geometry(2001, null, d.end_geo, NULL,
    NULL),
                          0.001) AS distance
FROM
    distances